# Is there a way to group Wordpress search results by page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

On my search results page, I have the standard loop that outputs pages and posts from the search query.

However, I want to create a group or section that gets all of the search results that return `is_page_template('template-procedure-minimal')` as `TRUE` first (preferably with a heading), and then output the rest of the list as usual.

How can this be done?

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
<hr class="dotted">
<div id="search-results" class="marginbottom2">
    <?php if(have_posts()) {
        // Results found
        global $wp_query;
        echo '<p>'.$wp_query->found_posts.' result'.(($wp_query->found_posts > 1) ? 's' : null).' found.</p>';
        while(have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
        }
        get_template_part('nav', 'below');
    } else {
        // No results
        echo '<p>Sorry, your search returned nothing. Did you spell it correctly?</p>';
    } ?>
</div>
<p class="lead halfmargin">Can't find what you're looking for?</p>
<p><a href="/contact-us/" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_pate_template_slug()` function to determine which template is using. 
Here is an example (I haven't tested this code):

`

```
    $page_template_posts = array();
    // Results found
    global $wp_query;
    echo '<p>'.$wp_query->found_posts.' result'.(($wp_query->found_posts > 1) ? 's' : null).' found.</p>';
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $post_template = get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID());
        array_push($page_template_posts[$post_template], get_post(get_the_ID()));
    }

    foreach ($page_template_posts as $key => $page_template_post){
        echo '<div>'. $key .'</div>';
        foreach ($page_template_post as $post_obj) {
            echo '<li><a href="'. get_the_permalink($post_obj->ID) .'">'.get_the_title($post_obj->ID).'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    get_template_part('nav', 'below');
} else {
    // No results
    echo '<p>Sorry, your search returned nothing. Did you spell it correctly?</p>';
} ?>
```

`

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite know how to comment on this. I appreciate you haven't tested it, but there are warnings all over the page, and it's not pulling back any posts. Besides, there's no way for me to specify the template. Perhaps you misunderstood what I'm trying to do... Can I make a new custom query, inside of the main query loop?